# Keep background behind text during browser resize

Tags: html, css

I've a question. I'm trying to keep a background behind navigation elements but when I resize the screen height by keeping the width, the background isn't wide enough and minimizes. This is my code:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 650px;
  height: 380px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: scroll;
  resize: both;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/JpmUqE8.png);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-position: right top;
  background-size: cover;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-right: 70px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

span {
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
  <div class="nav">
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to keep the background behind the links even if the screen get's smaller? It's okay when the image get's cut off at the bottom but it's important for the links to stay visible. If this is not possible, does someone has an alternative idea?

**UPDATE**

This is the problem I mean. If the image would hold it's size, the problem would not be a problem anymore:

[image]

Comment: Cannot replicate based the "working" image I added.

Comment: @Paulie_D Strange, I see the image. Give me a second pls.

Comment: @Paulie_D Can you see the image now?

Comment: The problem occurs because the background image has `background-size: cover`. This makes the background size dynamic, while the elements are not.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Try to resize my example and you will see the problem.

Comment: @agrm Any idea how to deal with this in a good way? I've played a lot with it and cant find a good way.

Comment: If you change the background size to `background-size: 650px 380px` and add `background-repeat: no-repeat` you will make the background size static. Not sure if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

Use the nav as reference for your background. Note that I have used a different image where I cropped the left space:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 650px;
  height: 380px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: scroll;
  resize: both;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-right: 70px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height:100%;
  padding:0 60px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xhx6.png);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-position:  top;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

span {
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
  <div class="nav">
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good idea but the problem is that I can't change the element where the background get's attached. The navigation on my site is complicated and animated so it will make the background looks bad. Maybe there is another solution?

Comment: So now way or how should I understand it? If yes, I need to try to change the DOM.

Comment: @Mr.Jo actually I don't have any other idea. Wait for more answers, they will probably bring more solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 650px;
  height: 380px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: scroll;
  resize: both;
  background-image: url("https://mk0brandloomtrca7pl1.kinstacdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/creative-website-designing-company-in-delhi-1999x1999.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  background-position: right top;
  background-size: contain;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  color: #000;
  margin-right: 70px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

span {
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
  <div class="nav">
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
    <span>Link</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has nothing todo with my question I think. Maybe read it again and check the correct image because Paulie removed my image before without knowing the problem.

Comment: Okay no Problem - @Mr.Jo